# AWS SAM: Lambda with two trigger events: Visualizer not showing S3 Trigger Event (but the trigger is still working)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I am using SAM to deploy this very simple architecture (one bucket and one lambda function triggered by a monthly scheduler and also by file uploads on the bucket).

```
Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:            
      BucketName: my-crazy-bucket-asdfasdfasdf-122326

  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: gitSamExample/someCode/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        NTrig:
            Type: Schedule
            Properties:
              Schedule: cron(47 10 12 * ? *)
              Name: TwelvthOfEachMonth
              Description: Example schedule
              Enabled: True
              
        FileUpload:
            Type: S3
            Properties:
                Bucket: !Ref MyS3Bucket
                Events: 
                    - s3:ObjectCreated:Put
                    - s3:ObjectCreated:Post
```

Issue: 
After successfully deploying the SAM template the FileUpload S3 trigger is not showing up in the lambda visualizer - only the Eventbridge is there:
[image: Missing S3 Trigger]

But the FileUpload trigger is definitely working and it shows also up on the bucket event list. When I try to add it up manually in the lambda visualizer I get of course this error message, that I cannot create such a trigger, because it already exists:
[image: failing to add trigger manually]
Only after I tried to add it manually and I received that error message, the trigger shows now up mysteriously in the visualizer, too:
[image: Trigger is there, now...]

Any idea why this might be the case and to fix this?

Comment: This seems at most a small inconvenience and maybe a little bug on the part of AWS. You could always contact AWS to let them know, but I don't think there's more to be done.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I also thought after thinking about it more. Still strange because this is probably a scenario that is quite common. I opened a bug.